# (Invariant Violation: ReactMount) How to use JQuery plugins in react which alter the DOM after rending

Tags: jquery, reactjs, html5-video

I have the following component, a video player which uses a jQuery based plugin (AfterGlow). The component renders successfully, even after AfterGlow mutates the original  element, however, whenever any video player button is clicked, AfterGlow adds/removes a class to the VideoPlayer div. At this point the two DOM's are out of sync with each other and an Invariant Violation error is throw.

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';

class VideoPlayer extends React.Component {

  static propTypes = {
    files: React.PropTypes.array.isRequired
  };

  constructor() {
    super();
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    window.afterglow.init()
  }

  render() {
    let videoSources = this.props.files.map(function(source) {
      return (<source key={`${source}-source`} src={source} />);
    }.bind(this));

    return (
      <div className='VideoPlayer'>
        <video
          width="650" height="325" id="VideoPlayer" key="VideoPlayer" data-skin="dark" className='afterglow responsive'>
          {videoSources}
        </video>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default VideoPlayer;
```

The error:

```
invariant.js?4599:39 Uncaught Error: Invariant Violation: ReactMount: Two valid but unequal nodes with the same `data-reactid`: .2.$11.$VideoPlayer
```

I have tried the suggestions on this page: https://github.com/ryanflorence/react-training/blob/gh-pages/lessons/05-wrapping-dom-libs.md, however this doesn't seem to solve the issues of DOM manipulation after rendering (dynamically). How can React either ignore these DOM changes, or this element be rendered somehow statically? Or find a different video plugin.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not a React pro, but for me, the solution looks quite simple. Did you try setting the id property dynamically based on the video id? This way, the problem should disappear because each player has it's own ID.